# Is this question correctly closed as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: ["Cannot open include file corecrt.h" on a fresh Visual Studio 2017 installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70909191/cannot-open-include-file-corecrt-h-on-a-fresh-visual-studio-2017-installation)

The supposed duplicate of my question can definitely seem like a duplicate at a first glance, since the titles are similar due to the same error message showing up. For me, that's where the similarities end since the supposed duplicate is using a different build process, and hence causes the error in a different way. The error message is not the problem - the problem is the problem. And the problem of the supposed duplicate and my question indeed proved to not be the same at all. The process of finding and fixing the error is not similar either, and none of the proposed answers on the other question are even applicable to my question.

For me, the most important fact is that there is simply no way of someone else using this site, having the same issue as I was having, to have any chance (future or present) of finding the solution to their problem in the linked question. That's why I opened a new question - the cause of the problem is different and the solution is different, and even the environment is different. Only "duplicate" thing is the error message itself. Again - error message is NOT the problem.

Any other day, I'd leave this as it is and not worry about it too much but I've noticed this particular comment:

> [image: comment 1]

This comment clearly demonstrates that the user posting it did not understand the circumstances of the problem. The proposed solution is not in the slightest applicable to the situation. The user probably didn't bother to read the whole question. My problem is that that same user has closed the question as a duplicate, right after I responded to the comment:

> [image: comment 2]

What the user suggested wasn't even the issue at the end. Further investigation led to issues with uninstall process leaving folders where they shouldn't be. That's the fix, that was the problem. User made no attempt to post an answer to the question, but instead made a comment suggesting they were aware of the answer and then promptly closed the question.

User in question has a golden c++ badge, allowing them to single-handedly mark questions as duplicates.

What can be done now? Should I post an answer to my question on the supposed duplicate, even though the answer is not applicable? How do I prevent situations like these in the future? I've made every attempt and put in a lot of effort to make it clear that the similarly titled problems were not in fact similar, only to have a user still close the question after not even putting in the effort to read it.

Comment: IMO it is a dupe as the problem is exactly the same, only some details differ. New users tend to ask the same questions all over again. If no closing SO very soon would become completely unusable. On the other hand, it is not strictly a programming question. I generally vote to close questions like this as it is the configuration issue of the commercial tool.

Comment: @0___________ I agree - it's definitely not a pure programming question. Which stackexchange site would this issue be more suited for? I'm still confused about what to do with my knowledge of a fixed problem here - the solution for my problem does not fit the linked question. Should I post it there anyways? Seems odd, to answer a question with an answer to a different question.

Also, none of the answers on the linked question can fix my question at all - how are other users with the same problem as mine expected to find a solution in the future if they can't find my question?

Comment: IMO it is a question to be asked on MS pages.

Comment: While I technically agree with the idea of asking on MS pages, I will respectfully disagree with the premise that anything useful can come out of going on MS support forums and talking to cookie-cutter automated responses. I can still understand and accept closing the questions like these on the basis of not being programming-related.

Comment: According to advice on the duplicate of *this* question, which I accepted, I have done everything within my abilities to try and make sure my question isn't closed as duplicate and also exhausted every option except specifically tagging the user who closed the question (I have no desire to communicate with a user who made extra effort to exclude a question from the site instead of understanding the question itself) I also do not have enough reputation to participate in chat rooms. As the answer on the linked question suggests, I have given up. Not only on this question but on SO in general.

Comment: Re *"...but on SO in general"*: Rage quitting is an immature reaction. Please reconsider. One way to try to preempt users only skimming a question is to put the meta information about a question not being duplicate ***in comments***. That is where meta information belongs anyway. Prepare the comment in advance and post it right after posting the question (the first comment spot is very important and set the tone for the rest). The comment should contain ***evidence*** (incl. links) and arguments, answering the question *"This looks like a duplicate. Why isn't it?"*, not just a vague statement.

Comment: @0___________ Topics pertaining to programs and utilities used by programmers are on topic for Stack Overflow (within reason). A problem with an IDE almost certainly falls under this scope. Despite some overlap with SO users, neither ServerFault or SuperUser should be expected to have the expertise of using a programming IDE. Or do we need to start evaluating the [tag:vim], [tag:emacs], [tag:visual-studio-code], [tag:git], and [tag:svn] tags? On top of that, **this is an error they are getting during compilation**. How is that *not* programming related?

Comment: @PeterMortensen how is it immature? I have invested a significant amount of time to make absolutely sure the question is definitely not a duplicate. What I got in return was question closed by a person who doesn't *want* to understand the question. The person has been given the authority to do so, and does it without investing any effort or time. If you look at the new comment they left on the original question, they're doubling down. They're still wrong because what they're proposing is not an answer. Hard coding environment variables is not a solution. They still keep the question closed.

Comment: It's therefore clear to me that the site and the community of stack overflow does not want me spending my time here. It's abundantly clear that posting new questions is non-desirable behaviour. Posting new questions requires so much effort that it's most often easier to abandon the thing one is working on, rather than ask for help on SO. What a great Q&A site. It's also amazing how little moderation and how much power hostile users have. It would be immature to spend the time that I have on helping a hostile website for free, when I could be doing something productive with my life instead.